# Ghostscript: How can I move/scale eps content on target image?

Tags: transformation, ghostscript, postscript

I want to create a png file from an eps file with ghostscript. But I want to put it on a bigger image and control exactly where and how big (this means, I want to scale and move it).
I assume, that one should add some postscript commands in a "-c" argument to ghostscript.
I tried arguments like -c " 0.8 0.8 scale " and -c " 1 1 moveto ". 
But in this case no png file was created, without other error message.
My question: what is the proper way to do this?

Example command used by me:

gswin32c.exe -dPARANOIDSAFER -r288 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=195 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=256 -c " 1 1 moveto " -sDEVICE=png16m -o "testout.png"  "input.EPS"

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the [Adobe EPSF specification](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/5002.EPSF_Spec.pdf)

especially Section 2.6 "Graphics state". You will need to use scale as you suggest, and moveto. Note that 1 1 moveto moves the current point by 1/72 of an inch, so likely you won't be able to see any difference. Although you have used a -c switch to introduce PostScript, you haven't followed it with a -f to revert back to command line processing.

Try:

```
gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=png16m -r288 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=195 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=256 -sOutputFile="testout.png" -c "72 72 moveto" -f "input.EPS"
```

That should move the rendered image up and right by one inch each which you should be able to see. Using -sOutputFile rather than -o is in case you get something back on stdout. -o implies -dBATCH and -dNOPAUSE.

Comment: Many thanks, it seems to work this way. One addition: "moveto" does not seem to help, but "translate" does. "scale" works also.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't thinking clearly, you need translate to shift the origin so that 0,0 is where you want the bottom left of the EPS to be. YOu should also take account of the BoundingBox, which is in the header comments.